# What does a chained if construct do in Java?

Tags: java, if-statement, chained

From reading through the Oracle iLearning Java course, I am under the impression that using a 'chained if construct' is the equivalent of using the '&&' operator. So:

```
 if((5 < 10) && (5 < 6)) {
    run some code;
}
```

is the same as:

```
if(5 < 10) {
  if(5 < 6) {
        run some code;
    }
}
```

comparing the two, I find it hard to believe. I think I am very misunderstood.

Comment: The `run some code` will be run only if both the if conditions are met ... so they are equivalent

Comment: Yes, these two code snippets are completely equivalent

Answer (score 5):

We can rewrite this code as:

```
if(someCondition)` {
    if(otherCondition) {
        //code
    }
}
```

So both `someCondition` and `otherCondition` must be true for `//code` to be run. (Key word AND). So in this instance `if(someCondition && otherCondition)` is equivalent to the above code

---

Generally the reason why you would use nested `if`'s is if you wanted to check multiple conditions such as:

```
if(someCondition) {
   if(otherCondition1) {
      //code
   }
   else if(otherCondition2) {
     //code
   } else {
     //else
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't know what is going on under the hood, JDK got very powerfool tool called **javac**. Just compile those 2 classes and compare it's bytecode (I did it for you this time). So the first one

```
public class YouCantAvoidNullPointerLikeThat {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if((5 < 10) && (5 < 6)) {
            //run some code;
        }
    }
}
```

gives you this bytecode

```
javap -c YouCantAvoidNullPointerLikeThat.class
Compiled from "YouCantAvoidNullPointerLikeThat.java"
public class YouCantAvoidNullPointerLikeThat {
  public YouCantAvoidNullPointerLikeThat();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: return
}
```

And the next example:

```
public class YouCantAvoidNullPointerLikeThat {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(5 < 10) {
            if(5 < 6) {
                //run some code;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

is giving you bytecode like

```
javap -c YouCantAvoidNullPointerLikeThat.class
Compiled from "YouCantAvoidNullPointerLikeThat.java"
public class YouCantAvoidNullPointerLikeThat {
  public YouCantAvoidNullPointerLikeThat();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: return
}
```

So yea, the result of this 2 are equal

Answer (score 0):

Your examples are equivalent:

First:

```
if (someCondition && otherCondition) {
     //some code
}
```

Second:

```
if (someCondition) {
     if(otherCondition) {
        //some code
     }
}
```

The second example is called collapsible "if" statements and should be merged as first example to increase the code's readability.

[Sonar: rule about "collapsible if statements"](https://sbforge.org/sonar/rules/show/squid:S1066?layout=false)

Comment: Are you sure? Check my answer.

Comment: @Niver you are right about the second approach , "it will give you the possibility to handle more cases directly, which you can not handle immediately using the first approach."  But the question was formulated  without the others cases. For the question, Sonar give you an alert: Collapsible "if" statements should be merged

Answer (score 0):

The two ways are similar but they are not same. Let's think about the separate cases:

In the first case, using the `and` operator you have:

```
if(conditionOne && conditionTwo){
   //do something if both conditions are true
}
```

In the other case you have:

```
if(conditionOne){
   if(conditionTwo){
      //do something of both conditions are true
   }
   //here you know that condition one is true but condition two is false
}
```

As you can notice the second approach will give you the possibility to handle more cases directly, which you can not handle immediately using the first approach.

Answer (score 0):

Stating the obvious, 5 is less than 6 and 10 anyday, so you code will be executed in both cases because you can replace the conditions with

```
 if(true)
```

Or remove it